# How can I access Doctrine from within a ChoiceListInterface class?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to populate a choice list based on information contained within one of my entity classes, but I can't access Doctrine from within my class that extends ChoiceListInterface. How can I query for the proper entities from within the class?

Answer (score 0):

You should use/extend EntityChoiceList interface !

Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\ChoiceList\EntityChoiceList